# How to insert text to a pre-existing application?

Tags: windows, user-interface, insert

So sorry about the vague title...
I am working in this project where I need to retrieve some string of data in the format, e.g., "123456789", and once I get it, I need to insert that string into a pre-existing application (from which I have no control and can't modify it or to interface by any other way, but a UI "text box"). once the data is inserted, to simulate an enter.

The pre-existing program is a win32 desktop app (working with an embedded telnet console).

I'm retrieving the data via JS, so if I need to insert using another language there is no problem. any suggestions would be helpful.

I lack experience in GUI programming, I'm more of the backend type of programmer (and haven't work much with win32 apps... i'm more like a Linux rat)

Thanks beforehand and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes here in the future with some similar question (as it turns out we do not know all the terms all the time): you were looking for **Data scraping**, more precisely> **Screen automation**. So I found the solution for what I was looking for doing research on RPA. And found SikuliX and Robot Framework [here](http://blog.mykhailo.com/2011/02/how-to-sikuli-and-robot-framework.html)

Happy coding!